# How to fix this grails error? What it is about?

Tags: java, grails

I have this error and I don't know how to fix it and why it has occurred. I'm using grails 2.2.4 and jdk 1.7.0.  I am obviously doing something wrong. Did I forget to do something?

Hoping for some instructions.

```
| Error 2014-05-03 21:13:11,796 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
    Line | Method
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
->> 1549 | createPoolableConnectionFactory in org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1388 | createDataSource in     ''
|   1044 | getConnection in     ''
|    262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
->>  411 | handleNewInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1117 | createCommunicationsException in com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError
|    350 | <init> .  in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO
|   2408 | coreConnect in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   2445 | connectOneTryOnly in     ''
|   2230 | createNewIO in     ''
|    813 | <init> .  in     ''
|     47 | <init>    in com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
|    411 | handleNewInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
|    399 | getInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|    334 | connect . in com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver
|     38 | createConnection in org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory
|    582 | makeObject in org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory
|   1556 | validateConnectionFactory in org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
|   1545 | createPoolableConnectionFactory in     ''
|   1388 | createDataSource in     ''
|   1044 | getConnection in     ''
|    262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
Caused by ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
->>   79 | socketConnect in java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    339 | doConnect in java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl
|    200 | connectToAddress in     ''
|    182 | connect   in     ''
|    172 | connect . in java.net.PlainSocketImpl
|    392 | connect   in java.net.SocksSocketImpl
|    579 | connect . in java.net.Socket
|    528 | connect   in     ''
|    425 | <init> .  in     ''
|    241 | <init>    in     ''
|    259 | connect . in com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory
|    300 | <init>    in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO
|   2408 | coreConnect in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   2445 | connectOneTryOnly in     ''
|   2230 | createNewIO in     ''
|    813 | <init>    in     ''
|     47 | <init> .  in com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection
|    411 | handleNewInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
|    399 | getInstance in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|    334 | connect   in com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver
|     38 | createConnection in org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory
|    582 | makeObject in org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory
|   1556 | validateConnectionFactory in org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
|   1545 | createPoolableConnectionFactory in     ''
|   1388 | createDataSource in     ''
|   1044 | getConnection in     ''
|    262 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error isn't necessarily about Grails, though.  Grails is just bubbling up what it encountered from another layer.  When you read the exceptions, you see it goes a bit like this:

- Grails
- Spring Beans
- Apache DBCP
- MySQL
- java.net

At the very root of the problem is this:

> `Caused by ConnectException: Connection refused: connect`

You're trying to connect to a server that's not listening on that port.  Check your configuration files for remote host name and port, and verify that there is a server running and listening there.